# Refresh in Joomla

Tags: joomla, page-refresh

i have a Joomla site on a Apache/2.2.9 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.9 server and i would like it to refresh the page at 1 miniute past each hour to ensure the latest articles are shown, this is a radio website so listeners often have their browser open on the site for hours at a time.
Can this snippet be adapted to refresh at 1 miniute past each hour?

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) { 
var now = new Date(); 
var then = new Date(); 

if(now.getHours() > hours || 
   (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) || 
    now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) { 
    then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1); 
} 
then.setHours(hours); 
then.setMinutes(minutes); 
then.setSeconds(seconds); 

var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime()); 
setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
```

}

Thanks

Comment: I guess if you refresh the radio will stop playing and you will annoy your visitors. It would be better to do ajax calls to the server every 20 or so minutes to check if some new content appeared...

Comment: Hi silvo, The media player loads into a seperate bar so that shouldn't be a problem, but i will research the Ajax thing to see if i can get that to work.

Comment: if anyone wants to view the site to see what i mean it's at www.stompradio.com Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are already loading the pages in to a frame, no point in making this harder than it should be, just use a meta refresh set to 20 minutes or so.

Comment: hi Brent, yes this is what we are doing at the moment but we are getting complaints from listeners that when they are entering text into our chat box or forum the page refreshes and they loose it all, hence we are trying to keep it to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it in the end using this script, setting it to 1hr and uploading it 1 minute past... Simples

//enter refresh time in "minutes:seconds" Minutes should range from 0 to inifinity. Seconds should range from 0 to 59
var limit="60:0"

if (document.images){
var parselimit=limit.split(":")
parselimit=parselimit[0]*60+parselimit[1]*1
}
function beginrefresh(){
if (!document.images)
return
if (parselimit==1)
window.location.reload()
else{ 
parselimit-=1
curmin=Math.floor(parselimit/60)
cursec=parselimit%60
if (curmin!=0)
curtime=curmin+" minutes and "+cursec+" seconds left until page refresh!"
else
curtime=cursec+" seconds left until page refresh!"
window.status=curtime
setTimeout("beginrefresh()",1000)
}
}

window.onload=beginrefresh